How can I set timezone for griddb
How can I set timezone for griddb to PST?
I want to return db current time in PST timezone by default when executing the following query.
select now();
I have gone through GridDB documentation but it seems that it either does not support or they have not mentioned in technical documentation.

From my experience, GridDB will use the machine's time as its own. So if you want your GridDB to be in PST, you will need to set your host machine to also be in PST. As you have noted, the timezone feature is notably absent from their docs, meaning it's not a feature at the moment

I did like this feature to be part of grid DB
